# Expression for someone with the drive to put efforts into his interests

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there an expression to describe someone who is interested in a topic and then has the drive to actually put some efforts in learning that topic (someone who is not just superficially interested in something)?

Comment: That is a dedicated person. That person could also be called a "go getter".

Comment: They are often described as being ***driven***

Comment: They could be described as **motivated**.

Comment: Yeah, he's "a real go-getter".

Comment: Enthusiastic perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[determined](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/determined)***

> 1. resolute; staunch; unwavering.
> 2. decided; settled; resolved.

(Random House)

Answer (score 0):

**Enthusiast** (noun) [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enthusiast)

​

*A person who is very interested in and involved with a particular subject or activity.*